# Using ArcPy to handle topology error inspector

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, topology

I want to do topology check using Python, but I don't know whether ArcPy can realize the function in error inspector.

Can I call error inspector and get the error records (something like attribute table) using Python (when ArcMap is open)?

Answer (score 1):

You can export the errors using *export topology errors* geoprocessing tool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000015w000000 this will give you the same results as the error inspector.